# Apache Ivy & Settings File

Tags: apache, ant, ivy

I'm writing my first Ivy configuration for a new Java project and am trying to hook my ivy-settings.xml file up to my buildscript.

I've followed all the tutorials and have correctly added the `xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant"` namespace to my build.xml file. So far I've tried running my resolve and cleancache targets, which run `ivy:resolve` and `ivy:cleancache` respectively, and all seems to be working (Ant can find Ivy).

However...when I run ivy:resolve, it defaults to go right to the public repo. Since my resolvers are written to look in my SVN root, I have to conclude that Ivy does not see my ivy-settings.xml file and is going to the public repos by default.

I am purposely keeping my ivy-settings.xml file as a separate project in source control because it will be used by all my projects.

So my question:

**How do I instruct the Ant buildscipt to look for a checked-out version of ivy-settings.xml somewhere else in my file system, not just sitting there locally in the same directory as build.xml?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the settings file name to:

ivysettings.xml

If you want to change this default name and location (same directory as build file) use the "settings" task

### Update

This is how I ensure that the settings file is loaded before invoking the ivy **resolve** of **cleancache** tasks. Create a target called *init* that is declared as a dependency

```
<target name="init">
    <ivy:settings file="../../ivysettings.xml"/>
</target>

<target name="resolve" depends="init">
    <ivy:resolve/>
</target>

<target name="clean" description="Cleanup build directory">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="clean-all" depends="init,clean" description="Clean and purge caches">
    <!-- Purge the ivy cache -->
    <ivy:cleancache/>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark but you misunderstood my question. If I have a settings file stored way over in some other directory than my project, is linking the buildscript to my settis file as simple as <ivy:settings file="path/to/my/ivy-settings.xml"/>? Because if it is then Ivy is still not finding it. Example: <ivy:settings file="../../SomeOtherProject/build/ivy-settings.xml"/>

Comment: I can't comment without a code example. Sure you're calling the settings task before the resolve? (or cleancache)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of the settings task